# Flutter ScrollController removeListener

Tags: flutter

I want to know must we call `removeListener` on `dispose` of StatefulWidget? what about `scrollController.dispose();`

Is dart/flutter smart enough to automatically dispose it?

```dart
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(() { 
      print('TEST');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No flutter will not dispose it automatically you have to dispose it manually using dispose method.

Comment: Does Flutter dispose the ScrollController itself though if no listener is attached when you pop a view for example, or should you ALWAYS call dispose() regardless?